# emacs cider clear REPL buffer

Tags: emacs, cider

I simply want to clear the repl buffer so that a single prompt eg (`user>`) is left on the first line.

I have a keybinding:

```
(put 'erase-buffer 'disabled nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-<backspace>") 'erase-buffer)
```

But this gives the message :

> text is read only

There is the option `C-c C-o` but this only clears the last return value.

When using python, and `run-python` the following command `C-x M-o` which i believe is `comint-clear-buffer`

Comment: The `cider` buffer is read only so you won't be able to execute any edit commands within it. You could turn it into a writable buffer but I don't think that would be wise

Comment: In my `inf-python-mode` `C-x M-o` does nothing, can you please type `C-h k C-x M-o` and see which function does it call?

Comment: I tried, but it gave me nothing... had to dig until I found it defined in `comint`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cider-repl.el` provides a function `cider-repl-clear-buffer` which by default is bound to:

`M-x c-r--bu RET`

as `C-c M-b` is not used by cider-repl as far as I am aware:

```
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook
      '(lambda () (define-key cider-repl-mode-map (kbd "C-c M-b")
            'cider-repl-clear-buffer)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`cider-repl.el` also provides `cider-repl-handle-shortcut` which is bound to `,`.

Which will prompt you to many commands, such as `clear` (which you want), `ns` (to change namespace), `refresh`, `reload` and many others

I find pressing `,` followd by enter (to choose `clear`, faster/more convenient than the other answer.)

Note: you need to type `,` into the repl while the line is empty, it works for both evil and normal emacs keybinds